# NHibernate Mapping Problem

Tags: c#, nhibernate-mapping

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie` (
  `m_ID` varchar(9) NOT NULL
  `ReleaseDate` date 
  `Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL 
  PRIMARY KEY (`m_ID`),
  KEY `m_ID` (`ReleaseDate`,`Title`,)
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_director` (
  `dirID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dirName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dirID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dirName` (`dirName`)
) 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m_directs` (
  `m_ID` char(9) NOT NULL
  `dirID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `m_ID_2` (`m_ID`,`dirID`),
  KEY `m_ID` (`m_ID`),
  KEY `dirID` (`dirID`)
)
```

Also note that m_ID is set as a foreign key to movie table and dirID is set as a foreign key to m_director.

I do not understand how this would get mapped to an object like this one via mapping xmls.

```
public class Movie
{
public string MovieTitle{get;set;}
public IList<string> Directors;
public DateTime ReleaseDate;
}
```

I can see it would be fairly easy with a list tag if there was not an intermediary table between movie and m_director(eg m_directs), but for a schema like I have, I do not understand how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `public IList<string> Directors;` cant be a manytomany because string has no object identity so it cant be linked from different Movies. Therefor you cant map it with NHibernate as manytomany. best way would be to

```
public class Movie
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Director> Directors { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Directornames
    { get { return Directors.Select(dir => dir.Name); } }
}

public class Director
{
    public virtual int Id {get; protected set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

  <class name="Movie" table="movie">
    <id name="Id" column="m_ID"/>
    <property name="ReleaseDate"/>
    <property name="Title"/>
    <bag name="Directors" table="m_directs">
      <key column="m_ID" not-null="true"/>
      <many-to-many class="Director" column="dirID"/>
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="Director" table="m_director">
    <id name="Id" column="dirID"/>
    <property name="Name" column="dirName"/>
  </class>
```

then it would be also possible to give directors more information like Birthdate and so on.

Edited: *corrected typos and indentation of xml mapping (hence not shown) and added fluent mapping*

```
class MovieMap : ClassMap<Movie>
{
    public MovieMap()
    {
        Table("movie");

        Id(m => m.Id, "m_Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(m => m.Title);
        Map(m => m.ReleaseDate);

        HasManyToMany(m => m.Directors)
            .Table("m_directs")
            .ParentKeyColumn("m_ID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("dirID")
            .AsBag()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

class DirectorMap : ClassMap<Director>
{
    public DirectorMap()
    {
        Table("m_director");

        Id(d => d.Id, "dirID").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(d => d.Name, "dirName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok, then how do I map that list to my schema? Sorry still not fully understanding how nhibernate works =\

Comment: I'm playing with Fluent Nhibernate and it is helping me understand, but it looks like a Director class would need an IList<Movie> to work. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: @user623879: It doesn't need to, if you don't have a plan yet to iterate to the movies directed by a director, you can remove IList<Movie> under the Director class. You can try this example: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/07/using-checkbox-list-on-aspnet-mvc-with.html Try to remove the IList<Movie> of Genre class, the code will still work. It's trivial to setup IList on both sides of the class relation though, it's ok to just put them all :-)

Comment: +1. Name of the bag missing: `<bag name=0"Directors" table="m_directs">`. You can also remove the columns which are identical to the name.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger thx fixed. I'm not used to writing xml, mostly writing fluent mappings ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, definately understanding this better now...ya fluent is much easier to learn with since autocomplete gives u all the hints you need.